# Filtering second level of Many-to-Many relations in Django

Tags: django, reference, many-to-many, django-queryset

Consider three django models: AA, BB and CC.
AA has an M2M reference to BB and BB has an M2M reference to CC.

I have a single instance of AA. How do I execute a filter() QuerySet over the set of CC instances that are M2M related the the BB instances that are M2M related to that single AA instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
CC.objects.filter( bb__aa = aa_instance )
```

That produces a QuerySet you can further manipulate...

Found the answer in the django documentation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships).